# UITabBarController View Transition error

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uiviewanimation

OKay I have been working on this problem for a while now, And It is well beyond my expertise thus why I am asking for help again.

I am trying to animate the transition for a tabbarbutton click to another view. I have declared in both viewController (ViewWillAppear) methods the code below

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //TODO: Fix transition animation

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
                           forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];  
}
```

FirstViewController to the right and SecondViewController to the left.

Now the problem is happening when the user loads the app for the  first time, once everything loads up and the user clicks on the tabbarbutton to go to the second view, it dose not flip.. but when you go back to the FirstView it animates then if you go to the second again it will animate this time round.. Dose anyone have any idea why this is happeneing? if you do your help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE::
I am trying to add a animation into viewDidLoad, however there is already an animation for an opening sequence I am loading straight away.

```
[super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //-- Start Opening Animation ------->
    CGRect vaultTopFrame = vaultTop.frame;
    vaultTopFrame.origin.y = -vaultTopFrame.size.height;

    CGRect vaultBottomFrame = vaultBottom.frame;
    vaultBottomFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    vaultTop.frame = vaultTopFrame;
    vaultBottom.frame = vaultBottomFrame;

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:vaultTop];   //this should place this subview above any others on the same page
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:vaultBottom]; //this should place this subview above any others on the same page

    [UIView  commitAnimations];
```

I think this might be messing things up for me what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have animation when the app loads up. Set animation in `viewDidLoad` for animation when the view loads  up and `viewDidAppear` will give you animations when the user makes transition after wards (every time the tab is clicked).

Comment: I actually have this other animation happening in my first view controller, How can I run the two without interfering with each other.

Comment: I don't really get you. How would they interfere with each other ?

Comment: well I will add the code of the other animation running in viewDidLoad, when I now run it the original animation I had in the method runs fine, however the tabbaricons do this weird slide across the screen... I will edit the above to include the first animation

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be the problem, but you should call

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

at the beginning of the method, before your animation code.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I have tried before and after... in desperation to see if this made a difference, I will move it back above like it should be :) thanks for taking the time to help though.